# Как получить значение FullPrimaryScreenWidth в Trigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Trigger Property="Width" Value="{Binding
        Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth},
        ConverterParameter={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth},
        Converter={StaticResource ConverterInt}}">
```

Конвертер:

```
public class ConverterInt : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value;
    }
```

> Exception: Не удается найти ресурс с именем "ConverterInt". Имена ресурсов определяются с учетом регистра.

после добавления     `<local:ConverterInt x:Key="ConverterInt"/>`

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Binding" нельзя задать в свойстве "Value" типа "Trigger". "Binding" можно задать только в параметре DependencyProperty объекта DependencyObject."

Comment: Вы добавили конвертер в ресурсы? Покажите как. PS: привязки, триггеры и прочее лучше ставить на `ActualWidth`, а не на `Width`.

Comment: `Application.Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = a };`

Comment: К чему это? **Покажите как вы добавили в ресурсы *конвертер*.**

Comment: Если вы так и не поняли о чем я, читайте это: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_1.php

Comment: Меняйте Trigger на DataTrigger

Answer (score 0):

Скорее вам нужно это:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```